# ServerSentEvents - Http Response Status Code

Tags: javascript, eventsource

How can I catch the http status code of a failed `EventSource` connection?

```js
function onError(event) {
  console.log('request status code?');
}

const source = new EventSource('url', { withCredentials: true });
source.addEventListener('error', onError);
```